# confusion over using auto-mapper in repository pattern .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im trying to implement something with some hard coded data,first of all,this hard coded data should be in my class model or in my repository?as far as i learend repository is to implement the logic of the project right?

I have a student model:

```
 public class Students
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; } = default!;
    public string StudentsName { get; set; }
    public string StudentsFname { get; set; }

   
}
```

I have a service to get all students:

```
 public  interface IGetStudent
{
    public IEnumerable<Students> GetStudent();
}
```

here in my StudentRepository I have :

```
 public class StudentRepository : IGetStudent
{

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public  StudentRepository(IMapper mapper)
    {

        _mapper = mapper;

    }
  
    public  IEnumerable<Students> GetStudent()
    {


        var newstudent = Student.ToList();
        return null ;



    }

    public  readonly List<Students> Student = new()
    {

        new Students()
        {

            StudentID = 123,
            StudentsName = "Moris",
            StudentsFname = "jackson"

            },
             new Students()
             {
               StudentID = 124,
               StudentsName = "Jack",
                StudentsFname = "sl"
              }

              };
              }
```

well,first of all,these hardcoded data should be in my repository or in my model?and if i want to use Automapper i should create another class like StudentsViewModel and map my student class to it?
the mapping logic should be in my controller or repository?

I really appreacite any help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's better to have a service layer that is responsible to map your entity to a ViewModel, but if you do not have a service layer, you can map your entity in your **controller**.

You should create a **StudentsViewModel**, but for mapping, you need to create a profile that configures your Student entity to StudentViewModel.

This Link is a good example of AutoMapper [Example](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)

and This link, is a good example of your senario [Example](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/automapper-in-aspnet-core/)

And about **StudentRepository** :

You hardcoded your student list in a right place, after a while you can read the student list from a Database.